# probability with replacement ("at least" scenario)

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to improve my stat skills from a book (Freedman et al, 2007, Statistics) that gives an exercise, I cannot get my head around.

It goes like this:

> There are $5$ green balls and $1$ red ball in a box. We draw four times randomly with replacement. What is the probability that we draw at least two red balls?

My guess would be:

$(1/6)^2 + (1/6)^3 + (1/6)^4$, because the probability of at least $2$ red balls out of $4$ draws must be equal to drawing two or three or four times a red ball. Hence I would use the addition rule, which gives $0.03 = 3$ percent

However, the book says it is $13$ percent, and gives the following explanation,
$$\frac{150+20+1}{1296}$$

Why is this so?

My attempt to trace back the terms:

I can possibly see how it got the first and third term in the fraction: The first could be $(5/6)^2 = 25/36$, which is the probability of drawing two green balls; and the third could be $(1/6)^4 = 1/1296$, which is the probability of drawing four red balls. I have no idea though where they could possibly get the $20$ from.

Thanks

Comment: The logic is correct.  The terms are wrong.   See Mark's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of getting exactly 2 red balls is 
$$
\left(\frac16\right)^2\left(\frac56\right)^2\binom{4}{2} = \frac{25}{1296}\cdot 6
$$
where the binomial coefficient is just the number of ways you can select which two picks, out of the four, got red balls.

The probability of getting exactly 3 red balls is 
$$
\left(\frac16\right)^3\left(\frac56\right)^1\binom{4}{1} = \frac{5}{1296}\cdot 4
$$
where the binomial coefficient is just the number of ways you can select which one pick, out of the four, got a red ball.  That is where the $20$ comes from.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, the probablity of getting exactly 4 red balls is:
(1/6)^4 x 4!/(4! 0!) = 1/1296 
I forgot the binomial formula, thank you!